Does composite API not support chatter posts?
Is there an official documentation which shows what list of rest api does composite api supports?
I tried this composite api request body.
POST_URL : {{_endpoint}}/services/data/v59.0/composite

{
    "allOrNone": true,
    "compositeRequest": [
        {
            "method": "PATCH",
            "url": "/services/data/v59.0/sobjects/Case/500al00000Ht0vH",
            "referenceId": "caseUpdate",
            "body": {
                "Status": "Working"
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/services/data/v59.0/chatter/feed-elements",
            "referenceId": "newFeedElement",
            "body": {
                "body": {
                    "messageSegments": [
                        {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "text": "When should we meet for planning?"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "feedElementType": "FeedItem",
                "subjectId": "500al00000Ht0vH" // Your valid Case ID
            }
        }
    ]
}

But seems like /services/data/v59.0/chatter/feed-elements is not supported via composite apis.
I get in response.
{
    "compositeResponse": [
        {
            "body": [
                {
                    "errorCode": "PROCESSING_HALTED",
                    "message": "The transaction was rolled back since another operation in the same transaction failed."
                }
            ],
            "httpHeaders": {},
            "httpStatusCode": 400,
            "referenceId": "caseUpdate"
        },
        {
            "body": [
                {
                    "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
                    "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
                }
            ],
            "httpHeaders": {},
            "httpStatusCode": 404,
            "referenceId": "newFeedElement"
        }
    ]
}   

If I try to fire {{_endpoint}}/services/data/v59.0/chatter/feed-elements separately, it works fine and adds chatter posts on case.

You can read through the developer docs here, the chatter APIs are not supported.
From the docs,
Composite is supported for the only following resources.
All sObject resources (/services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/), including sObject Rows by External ID and excluding sObject Blob Get
The Query resource (/services/data/vXX.X/query/?q=soql)
The QueryAll resource (/services/data/vXX.X/queryAll/?q=soql)
The sObject Collections resource (/services/data/vXX.X/composite/sobjects). Available in API version 43.0 and later.
